# Вывести с группировкой данные MY SQL через PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

Доброго времени суток!
Проблема такая:
Есть таблица в БД:

```
id  | format | address | factory | phonezav | phonegor | fio | status |
```

Мне надо вывести ее сгруппировав по полю `factory`. т.е выводим заголовок(Одна строка) или одну строку а ниже все кто входят в этот 
Как так вывести элементы через PHP?

Просто вывод данных

```
<?
while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc())!= false):                 

    echo   '<tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>'.$row['format'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['factory'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['phonezav'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['phonegor'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['fio'].'</td>';
    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: И с чем возникли проблемы?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не могу вывести сгруппированный список.
т.е.
1-я строка это группа
2 и след все кто входит в эту группу

Comment: Что такое "группа"? Из чего она состоит? Из одного поля `factory`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Сгруппировать  по полю `factory` в вывести

Comment: Это я уже слышал. Вы пишете `т.е. 1-я строка это группа` Я хочу узнать, что такое у Вас группа, из чего она состоит и чем отличается от последующих строк?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Смотрите: есть десять строк, у которых `factory` равно "ЗАВОД1" и 20  - "ЗАВОД2", и 60 - "ЗАВОД "Меня прет!"". Далее вывод и получаем: первая строка название группы "ЗАВОД1".И пошли ниже перечислять все 10(!) строк. Потом идет "ЗАДОД2" и у него тоже есть список из 20 строк - выводи из ну и т.д и т.п. Вот мне и надо СГРУППИРОВАТЬ их, а строка завод повторяется 10 , 20 и 60 раз соответственно. Извините, плохо объясняю! С теорией плохо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте обычный `ORDER BY`. Тогда все одинаковые `factory` у вас будут идти подряд. И Вам останется только текущий `factory` с предыдущим, чтобы узнать не сменилась ли группа

```
$res = $con->query('SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY factory');
if (!$res)
  die($con->error);
$oldFactory = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
  if ($res['factory'] !== $oldFactory) {
    printf('<tr><td>%s</td></tr>', $res['factory']);
    $res['factory'] = $oldFactory;
  }
  echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$row['format'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['factory'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['phonezav'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['phonegor'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['fio'].'</td></tr>';

}
```